# Selecting Reactable Rows via Leaflet Map with Crosstalk

Tags: r, leaflet, reactable, crosstalk

In the code below from https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#cross-widget-interactions, I'd like to be able to highlight the row entry by clicking on the map icon, i.e. the reverse of clicking on the table entry.

Is that possible (without Shiny)?

```
library(crosstalk)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

# A SpatialPointsDataFrame for the map.
# Set a group name to share data points with the table.
brew_sp <- SharedData$new(breweries91, group = "breweries")

# A regular data frame (without coordinates) for the table.
# Use the same group name as the map data.
brew_data <- as_tibble(breweries91) %>%
  select(brewery, address, village, founded) %>%
  SharedData$new(group = "breweries")

map <- leaflet(brew_sp) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers()

tbl <- reactable(
  brew_data,
  selection = "multiple",
  onClick = "select",
  rowStyle = list(cursor = "pointer"),
  minRows = 10
)

htmltools::browsable(
  htmltools::tagList(map, tbl)
)
```